# Highlight certain days for Angular Material Datepicker (>ng2)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it somehow possible to highlight certain days / months (when in year view) using the **[Angular Material Datepicker?](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)** 
Like the displayed dates should be tested against a function in the component the datepicker is in and if that function returns true, then a CSS class should be added. 
So basically **something like `ngClass` for the displayed days / months** (when in year view).